# R：ERROR in coxph after multiple imputation. overlapping intervals for one or more subjects

Tags: r

Here is my code, after imputation for the variable "APACHEII",but if i coxph dataset"dm5" directly, error won't be reported:

```
dm5<-fread(kwd %&% "dm5_1218.csv",header = TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dm5[, id:= str_extract(Case_No_N,"[0-9]+")]
dm5<-cbind(dm5,factor2ind(dm5$ICU_Ward,"CICU"))
colnames(dm5)[44:47]<-c("NICU","RICU","SICU","TICU")
dm5 <- unique(dm5)
str(dm5)
miss <- function(x){sum(is.na(x))/length(x)*100}
apply(dm5,2,miss)
md.pattern(dm5)
str(dm5)
dm5<-dm5[,-c("ICU_Ward","Case_No_N","ICU_No_N","time","ICU_Day","onset",
          "ICU_onset","Age_F","Age_F_G","Admisson_Date_F","Discharge_Date_F")]


dm5<-as.data.frame(dm5)
numeric_var<-c("APACHEII","tstart","tstop","id")  
factor_var<-c("AGE_F_G2","AGE_F_G3","AGE_F_G4","Sex_F",
              "NICU","RICU","SICU","TICU","HAP","diabetes",
              "IHD","Heart_failure","chronic_lung","pulmonary_vasculature","diabetes","hypertension","chronic_lung",
              "cancer","hypertension","ICU_Diag_ARDS","ICU_Diag_Feiyan","ICU_Diag_shock","ICU_Diag_blood",
              "mir","antibiotics_day","liver_failure","kindey_failure","cardiac_surgery","cranial_surgery",
              "mianyiyzj_day")
for (i in numeric_var) {
  dm5[,i]<-as.numeric(dm5[,i])
}

for (i in factor_var) {
  dm5[,i]<-as.factor(dm5[,i])
}

str(dm5)

dm5<-as.data.table(dm5)

pre<-make.predictorMatrix(dm5)
pre[c("APACHEII"),"id"]<- -2  ###setting group
# pre["lipid_day","ICU_Ward"]<-0
pre[,c("tstart","tstop")]<-0  ###variables donnot need for imputation

meth<-make.method(dm5)
meth
meth[c("APACHEII")]<-c("2lonly.mean")
imp<-mice(dm5,pre=pre,meth=meth,seed=12345)
```

and here is the error reported:Error in coxph(Surv(tstart, tstop, HAP) ~ Sex_F + AGE_F_G2 + AGE_F_G3 +  :
data set has overlapping intervals for one or more subjects

i cannot understand why the process of imuptation will influence the running of coxph, thanks for your answers!

Comment: Can you please provide a minimum reproducible example, this is currently not reproducible as the data is not provided. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

i solve this question just now.
when you first meet this error report, you should go to check your data first. in a longitindual data(with a same id for rows), some fixed covariates should keep consistency in these rows.